# Sharepoint 2010 - The search request was unable to connect to the Search Service

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2010

This has been frustrating me for days now.

I am trying to use Sharepoint Search (not Fast), and I just want to be able to enter a search term and have relevant results returned from the site.

So I have gone through setting up a Search App with all the trimmings about 3 times. 
I can monitor the crawl and its going well.  (Did it once via powershell as well)

So everything seems to be setup on the "server side" 
I have ensured that the relevant ( I think) Windows Services are running and seems to work.

Now what happens is when I create a Search site on the site I am in, when I execute a search I always get the response "The search request was unable to connect to the Search Service."   And I have not managed to "connect" my search site with the search application it seems.

Now I have looked through the trace log and I have looked through the event logs, and I have failed to find an entry so far that corresponds to the difficulty in "connecting".
If someone knows of others logs I ought to look at that would be super.

If anyone has an idea of what in the world is going wrong. please let me know.

Our "Farm" is one web front end and one app server.

I have configured one Sharepoint 2010 site before with Search and I did not encounter any of these problems.  I didnt do the install and base configuration of this environment though I am just troubleshooting it.

Comment: is your search site part of same site collection or you have created it in new one. my point of asking this one is to make sure your crawled content source and your search site are using the same search app

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally found the answer here [Sharepoint 2010 - The search request was unable to connect to the Search Service.](http://web.archive.org/web/20130329010647/http://williamkent.net/archive/2010/12/10/sharepoint-2010---the-search-request-was-unable-to-connect.aspx)

> There can be a couple of different reasons for this error message, such as ensuring that the right service account is running the Search Windows Service, however there is one quick thing to check that might fix your issue.
>
> 1. Goto Central Administration
> 2. Application management
> 3. Manage Web Applications
> 4. Select the web application
> 5. Click on Service Connections
> 6. Ensure that the search application you configured is checked in this list.

If you go to edit your web app in central admin you will see that there is a
button along the top called "Service Connections". Please ensure that your search 
app is selected in the form that pops up.

Answer (score 6):

Central Admin -> Service Applications ->Manage service applications make sure your search service application is running with a proxy just below it.  If not, likely because you did a backup and the proxy requires a second backup, from the ribbon select New -> Search Service Application.

Once created successfully go to CA -> Web Applications -> Manage web applications.  Highlight the sharepoint port 80 site and select Service Connections.  Make sure your new proxy is selected.

Then under CA -> Application Mgmt -> Manage services on server select Sharepoint Server Search select the new service you setup and make sure the topology looks ok.  Then schedule and start a new Full crawl.  All set.

AND

Don't forget to add the pdf file type if you've set that up under the old search app before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Here are the steps to fix this problem:

1. Right click on My Computer and Goto Computer management.
   Select Services and applications
   Start indexing service If not started.
2. - Central Admin > Application Management > Office SharePoint Server Shared Services > Create or Configure this farm’s shared services
   - Shared Services Provider (drop down) > Edit Properties
   - Edit Shared Services Provider > Index Server: Verify the index server is set
3. Single Server Farm

   On the MOSS 2007 server:

   - `Start > Run > CMD > stsadm.exe -o osearch -action stop`
   - `Start > Run > CMD > stsadm.exe -o osearch -action start -role query index`

   Multiple Server Farm

   On the MOSS 2007 Front End Web/Query server:

   - `Start > Run > CMD > stsadm.exe -o osearch -action stop`

   On the MOSS 2007 Index server:

   - `Start > Run > CMD > stsadm.exe -o osearch -action stop`

   On the MOSS 2007 Index server:

   - `Start > Run > CMD > stsadm.exe -o osearch -action start -role index`

   On the MOSS 2007 Front End Web/Query server:

   - `Start > Run > CMD > stsadm.exe -o osearch -action start -role query`
4. - Go to Central Admin ->Operations ->Topologies and services ->Services on server
   - Click “Office SharePoint Server Search”
   - Make sure the user has sufficient permission to access database.

Note: If your Search query and indexing server are same then set both options “Use this server for indexing content” and “Use this server for serving search queries” to true.

Comment: I am sorry the question was in regards to 2010. The behavior of search changed dramatically between 2007 -> 2010.

Comment: Restart all services and check.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 Tips check list

- make sure that you have the [default] setting in  Service Connections for your web applications or that newyly created Search Service is selected for the Web App you want to be crawled . it is different is search service is installed and started on that server or not
- check missing search service proxy and create a search proxy with below command or connect in services

  $searchServiceApp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
  New-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplicationProxy -SearchApplication $searchServiceApp
- restarting search service in the resolved the problem
- always wait for this service status to be updated in Central admin because it is a bit slow and different  components (Admin, Crawler,    Content Processing, Analytics Processing,   Query Processing    ,Index Partition)

source:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2888383